# Unable to include .model files for objects in .world file (for simulation) in Ubuntu 12.04 fuerte

Tags: gazebo, ros-fuerte, newtags

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

After installing Ubuntu 12.04 and fuerte (today), I am unable to launch most of my world file, which were running smoothly on electric on Ubuntu 11.10.

as per the error I think there is some new way to include  .model file of an object in the .world file. Kindly provide me the pointers for that.

To test (that error is not with my made .world and .model files), I included simple_office_table.world file from gazebo_world package.

The .model files are included as : (in simple_office_table.world file)

```
.
.
  <model:physical name="desk4_model">
    <xyz>2.28  -0.21  0</xyz>
    <rpy>0.0 0.0 0.0 </rpy>
    <include embedded="true">
<xi:include href="../objects/desk4.model" />
    </include>
  </model:physical>


  <model:physical name="desk5_model">
    <xyz>2.25  -3.0   0</xyz>
    <rpy>0.0 0.0 0.0 </rpy>
    <include embedded="true">
      <xi:include href="../objects/desk5.model" />
    </include>
  </model:physical>
.
.
```

and my launch file is

```
<launch>
  <arg name="use_sim_time" default="true"/>
  <arg name="gui" default="true"/>

  <group if="$(arg gui)">
    <node name="gazebo_gui" pkg="gazebo" type="gui" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
  </group>

</launch>
```

When I launch it in fuerte I get error saying Opening and ending tag mismatch, as:-

```
Msg Waiting for master.Warning [parser.cc:348] Gazebo SDF has no gazebo element
Entity: line 211: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: physical line 206 and include

          ^
Entity: line 212: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: world line 3 and physical

                 ^
Entity: line 215: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document

^
Error [parser_deprecated.cc:1365] Could not parse the xml
Entity: line 211: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: physical line 206 and include

          ^
Entity: line 212: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: world line 3 and physical

                 ^
Entity: line 215: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document

^
Error [parser_deprecated.cc:1307] Could not parse the xml
Error [parser.cc:263] parse as old deprecated model file failed.
Error [Server.cc:196] Unable to read sdf file[/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds/simple_office_table.world]
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 9413, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gazebo /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds/simple_office_table.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/nirala/.ros/log/a44e752a-fdd7-11e1-b21f-7071bc63a65c/gazebo-2.log].
log file: /home/nirala/.ros/log/a44e752a-fdd7-11e1-b21f-7071bc63a65c/gazebo-2*.log
^C[gazebo_gui-3] killing on exit

Error [ConnectionManager.cc:89] Connection Manager is not running
[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

apart from the  harmless AttributeError as discussed at : http://answers.ros.org/question/34304/exception-attributeerror-when-starting-roscore/

A similar error is also posted at : http://answers.ros.org/question/29622/import-dae-gazebo-100-rc2/

Am I missing some small configuration or tags somewhere? Kindly help me out.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43809/unable-to-include-.model-files-for-objects-in-.world-file-(for-simulation)-in-ubuntu-12.04-fuerte/) by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2012-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No your fault, the parser does not work with `<include>` tags correctly, [ticketed](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5558).  Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1